# TcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync method not listen to a client request

Tags: c#, tcp, tcplistener

I'm trying to do a TCP server in C#.

My code look like this:

```
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 4201);
server.Start();
var client = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
//do something with the client.
```

The issue is that when i call to that TCP server, it is still stack on the method `AcceptTcpClientAsync()`.

A java code that i used in order to try to connect to the above server:

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4201);
```

and I'm getting the exception in java -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225)
```

When I'm trying to open ServerSocket in java like:

```
ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(4201);
Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
//do something with the connectionSocket.
```

Everything is working properly and I'm able to connect to the server, so i guess the issue is not in the port or in the firewall.

In any case I added a firewall rule -

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open port 4201" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=4201
```

But still the C# server not working.

Any idea what can i try in addition?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't reproduce, works correctly for me

Comment: When you mention that you can connect "to the server", it sounds to me like you're connecting from a different machine? (in that case "127.0.0.1" would of course not work)

Comment: hi C.Evenhuis, all my attempts to connect was from my local to my local...